# Oledb update sql statement example

Tags: sql, oledb, statements

```
con.Open();
cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE staff SET StaffNr = @a, FirstName = @b, 
    Surname = @c, Email = @d, Balance = @e WHERE Email = @d", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", textBoxStaffName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", textBoxStaffSur.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", textBoxStaffE.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", double.Parse(textBoxSatffBal.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", int.Parse(textBoxStaffNr.Text));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

not updating the database for some reason but the code runs

Comment: Do you get any exceptions thrown? Also, telling us what RDBS may be useful

Comment: OleDB uses `?` for parameters, not `@x`.

Answer (score 0):

OldDb uses `?` for parameters, not `@x`. You have to add parameters in order. The name is ignored in `AddWithValue` (this method comes from a general purpose superclass)

```
con.Open();
cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update staff set StaffNr = ?, FirstName = ?, 
    Surname = ?, Balance = ? Where Email = ?", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", int.Parse(textBoxStaffNr.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", textBoxStaffName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", textBoxStaffSur.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", double.Parse(textBoxSatffBal.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", textBoxStaffE.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```